# Select all buttons that don't contain a class, Multiple options

Tags: javascript, html, button

I'm trying to select all buttons that don't contain the following classes.
.remoteCall, .refreshHistory

The following code works if I have one property passed, but it doesn't work with two.

```
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button:not(.remoteCall), button:not(.refreshHistory)');
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chaining the :not selectors should work:
`var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button:not(.remoteCall):not(.refreshHistory)');`

Comment: No problem. Could you mark the answer as the accepted answer?

Answer (score 0):

Alternative: filter

```
const buttons = [...document.querySelectorAll('button')]
 .filter(but => !but.classList.contains("remoteCall") && 
                !but.classList.contains("refreshHistory"))
```